# SUPEE-9767 V2 - V1 Patch reversal errors

Tags: patches, supee-9767

I'm trying to reverse SUPEE-9767 V1, but it fails:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-31-32.sh -R
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
Unreversed patch detected!  Ignore -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 120 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 10 (offset 3 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Any ideas where I should be looking to fix the reversal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have issue in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php`.

patches does not applied on that files that why you getting the issue.

To resolved this issue, **you should remove  patches code  for that class from Version1 file** sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-31-32.sh`

***remove the code below code from That Sh files***

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
index 4610c07..4396777 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
@@ -222,6 +222,8 @@ public function login($username, $password)
     public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
     {
         $this->setCustomer($customer);
+        $this->renewSession();
+        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();
         Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
         return $this;
     }
@@ -307,6 +309,7 @@ protected function _logout()
         $this->setId(null);
         $this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
         $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
+        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();
         return $this;
     }
```

Then  run PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v2-2017-07-11-11-01-10.sh  revert comment.

> ***Actually,AtVersion1 ,Patch does not applied Successfully at app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php.***.

Comment: How can I use your code?

Comment: After removing what you told, still not working @ Amit